# Multiple if conditions within nested repeat while in applescript

Tags: applescript

I've never used AppleScript before, so i'm quite unfamiliar with the language, but i'm doing my best.

Here's what i'm trying to accomplish:
Run a script while selecting a folder filled with .ARW and .JPG files. Iterate through the items in the folder. If the current item is .ARW, iterate through the folder starting from the beginning again. If this nested iteration lands on a file that has the same file name and a JPG extension, label the original ARW file with red.

TLDR: If an ARW file in a folder shares the same filename as a JPG file in the folder, highlight the ARW file in red, otherwise do nothing.

Here's the code i've written so far:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set totalAlias to the entire contents of (selection as alias)
    set totalCount to the count of items of totalAlias
    set firstName to name of item 1 of totalAlias
    set firstExtension to name extension of item 1 of totalAlias
    set c to 1

repeat while c ≤ totalCount
    set currentAlias to item c of totalAlias
    set currentName to name of currentAlias
    set currentExtension to name extension of currentAlias
    if currentExtension is "ARW" then
        set d to 1
        set compareFile to currentAlias
        set findName to currentName
        set findExtension to currentExtension

        repeat while d ≤ totalCount
            if (name of item d of totalAlias = findName) and (name extension of item d of totalAlias is "JPG") then
                tell application "Finder" to set label index of compareFile to 2

            end if
            set d to (d + 1)
        end repeat
    end if
    set c to (c + 1)
end repeat
end tell
```

Any thoughts on what's going wrong? I believe it has to do with my IF AND condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this script:

```
tell application "Finder"
    --Just get all the filenames of the target types:
    set allJPG to the name of every file of (entire contents of (selection as alias)) whose name extension = "JPG"
    set allARW to the name of every file of (entire contents of (selection as alias)) whose name extension = "ARW"
    --Send the two lists to a handler to find all the common names
    set targetJPGFiles to my CompareNames(allJPG, allARW)
    --Loop through the common names, find the files, set the tags
    repeat with eachTarget in targetJPGFiles
        set fileToTag to (item 1 of (get every file of (entire contents of (selection as alias)) whose name is (eachTarget as text)))
        set label index of fileToTag to 2
    end repeat
end tell

targetJPGFiles -- This allows you to see the filenames that SHOULD have been tagged

to CompareNames(jp, pn)
    --First, get rid of all the extensions in the ARW files
    set cleanARWNames to {}
    set neededJPGNames to {}
    repeat with eachARWName in pn
        set end of cleanARWNames to characters 1 thru -5 of (eachARWName as text) as text
    end repeat
    --Now, loop through JPG names to find a match
    repeat with eachjpgName in jp
        set searchName to characters 1 thru -5 of (eachjpgName as text) as text
        if cleanARWNames contains searchName then
            set end of neededJPGNames to (eachjpgName as text)
        end if
    end repeat
    return neededJPGNames
end CompareNames
```

It takes a slightly different approach, in that it just compares two lists of filenames only, then goes back, finds the files with the names you want, and does the tagging.

It is based on a script I wrote for another project, so I hope it works for  you.

I have never used the `label index` property in Finder before, and I found through some testing that I could not see the labels until I clicked on the folder after the script ran.  All the target files had the correct tag after I did that, though.

Comment: Hey Craig, thanks so much! I modified your script to highlight the ARWs instead of the JPGs and it works perfectly. I guess my only remaining question is why does it take so long for the script to execute (~3 minutes on a 3Ghz i7 MBPro for 40 ARWs)? Is there an inherent slowness in Applescript?

Comment: The slowness in this case results from the `entire contents` command.  That is designed to drill down through all subfolders in the chosen folder.  If you have no subfolders, you can use `every file of (selection as alias)` instead, and that should speed it up.  Other scripters believe that ANY time you use a `tell app "Finder"` block, you need to go make a sandwich while it runs.